# Sorry, but how do I mark a response as an answer?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I received a solution to my question but I how do I mark it as an answer and also ask for additional help with the sql.

Thanks

Davo

Comment: You should look for the answer in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Also this doesn't belong her.

Answer (score 0):

Below the relevant answer you may tick a green tick item to select it as answer. However I suggest you should read these as this isn't an appropriate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/tour
https://stackoverflow.com/help